# Silence E_DEPRECATED in php

Tags: php, exception, deprecated, error-reporting

I have one problem with disable show deprecated errors in php.
In my project are used a lot of deprecated function. This is very big project, so I can not replace this functions with non-deprecated this at the moment.

For this function:

`mcrypt_create_iv`

is throwing error ErrorException with message "Function mcrypt_create_iv() is deprecated".

How can I disable it?
I tried a lot of ways, and this is not throwing only if error_reporting == 0.

When error reporting is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  | E_CORE_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_USER_NOTICE | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_USER_WARNING | E_USER_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_CORE_WARNING | E_ERROR));
```

everythink is working, but if I remove only one flag I can see error on my screen.

Do you know any ideas?

I'm using PHP 7.1:

```
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2017 01:30:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I suggest you to not ignore deprecated warnings, because it's a sign that the feature you are using will be deleted in the future.

Comment: Realize that you are performing bitwise math here, and setting it to 0 would disable all errors the same and be faster.

Answer (score 0):

First, your [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) configuration seems a bit weird to me. You're enabling `E_ALL`, but then removing *everything*? Seems it would be better to just list those that you want to see, instead of excluding everything. This might be one reason for it being so touchy.

Second, it's better to leave error reporting on and adjust [other error-related settings](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php). Make it so errors are only visible in log files for your review. See: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
display_errors=no
log_errors=yes
error_log=/var/log/php/errors.log
```

Finally, if all else fails, you can avoid this warning using [`@` suppression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). This is not a great idea though, because you'll forget that this problem exists and eventually in a future release of PHP, this will break entirely as this deprecated function is removed. Also, by suppressing errors you're going to potentially miss other issues more important than a deprecation warning.

```
@mcrypt_create_iv(...); // Suppress errors.
// Last-ditch, last resort. Refrain from using.
```

---

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

> The mcrypt extension has been abandonware for nearly a decade now, and was also fairly complex to use. It has therefore been deprecated in favour of OpenSSL, where it will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2.

Comment: Yes I enabled E_ALL and disabled all for tests only.

Comment: `@` will suppress any error message that that call could possibly raise, not just deprecation notices. Real bad idea.

Comment: In 7.0, escaping a function with `@` does *NOT* suppress the deprecation warnings.